# How do I install Tweepy using Poetry?

Tags: python, tweepy, python-poetry

When I try installing by running this command, `poetry add tweepy`, it returns this error:

```
    (base) angellanaigaga@Angellas-MBP plugin-template % poetry add tweepy
Using version ^3.10.0 for tweepy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (13.6s)

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['git', '--git-dir', '/var/folders/pt/17xvwz550hx9hkhw2wv0zpbr0000gn/T/pypoetry-git-wr1sgu4u/.git', '--work-tree', '/var/folders/pt/17xvwz550hx9hkhw2wv0zpbr0000gn/T/pypoetry-git-wr1sgu4u', 'checkout', 'demo']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/_compat.py:217 in run
      213│                 process.wait()
      214│                 raise
      215│             retcode = process.poll()
      216│             if check and retcode:
    → 217│                 raise CalledProcessError(
      218│                     retcode, process.args, output=stdout, stderr=stderr
      219│                 )
      220│         finally:
      221│             # None because our context manager __exit__ does not use them.
```

Comment: It worked for me. Do you ave full traceback? It seems shorten

Comment: That's the full traceback. I only cropped out directory path but let me add it

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this:

```
>poetry add tweepy
Using version ^3.10.0 for tweepy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file

Package operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing oauthlib (3.1.1)
  • Installing pysocks (1.7.1)
  • Installing atomicwrites (1.4.0)
  • Installing attrs (21.2.0)
  • Installing more-itertools (8.8.0)
  • Installing py (1.10.0)
  • Installing colorama (0.4.4)
  • Installing pluggy (0.13.1)
  • Installing wcwidth (0.2.5)
  • Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.0)
  • Installing pytest (5.4.3)
  • Installing tweepy (3.10.0)
```

This seems like an issue with one of the other dependencies of your project.

From what I can gather, it seems to be attempting to install a (possibly nameless?) git dependency's `demo` branch, which probably doesn't exist.

It's difficult to determine more without seeing your pyproject.toml.